# Custom Authentication with external web service in ASP.NET Core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

I have an **external web service** which holds the user data & I need to use that to log user in. I would like to use existing AccountController + UI views if possible. I tried adding **custom SignInManager** class to override **PasswordSignInAsync** as below.

```
public class MySignInManager<ApplicationUser> 
: SignInManager<ApplicationUser> where ApplicationUser : MyModels.ApplicationUser
```

But it fails due to missing EF database which stores user information. I **do not need EF database** since this external web service will be my data source.

I read I need to implement UserManager & UserStore but could not find samples with ASP.NET Core release. Could someone point me to that?

Comment: Just implement the `IUser*` interfaces (depending on which features you want your store to support), then register it with the IoC container (like Identity does with EntityFramework here https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/5480aa182bad3fb3b729a0169d0462873331e306/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs#L45-L61)

Answer (score 0):

I found this implementation - [Aspnet Core Identity Without Entityframework](https://taherchhabra.github.io/jekyll/update/2016/09/22/aspnet-core-identity-without-entityframework.html)

[Source code on Github](https://github.com/taherchhabra/AspNetCoreIdentityWithoutEF)

I think this should be good enough to start with.

Comment: **Aspnet Core Identity Without Entityframework** is a broken link

Comment: Sorry, could not find article link, looks like GIThub link is still active.